# Update Cholesky factorization

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, cholesky-decomposition

I need to compute the Cholesky factorization of $H'H$ where $H$ is a big sparse rectangular matrix.

After that $H$ is modified by adding several lines. That is H_n = [H ; line_1 ; ... ; line_n] in Matlab. How can I recompute the Cholesky of $H_n'H_n$ fast? I.e. without factorization of the whole $H_n'H_n$ but using previously computed factor of the $H'H$.

Comment: Google is your friend: *update Cholesky decomposition* in wikipedia-

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition is about rank-1-update for the dense matrices. But I need to _add_ lines to _sparse_ matrix

Comment: Ok sparse, then what about this: https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/cholmod/CHOLMOD/Doc/UserGuide.pdf